# Como executar um find -exec em arquivos modificados a mais de 15 dias?

Tags: linux, script, bash

Eu estou tentando remover alguns arquivos de um diretório, porém não consigo montar um comando. O que eu quero seria mais ou menos assim:

```
find  -name '*.log*' -mtime 15 -exec rm -f {}
```

Achar o padrão do nome e remover os arquivos modificados a mais de 15 dias atrás.
Tentei o comando acima, porém me retorna que falta parâmetros no `-exec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, `-mtime 15` traz os arquivos modificados há exatamente 15 dias atrás. Se quiser os que foram modificados há **mais** de 15 dias, use `-mtime +15`.

Já para a opção `-exec`, faltou colocar um `\;`:

```
find  -name '*.log*' -mtime 15 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Ou um `+`:

```
find  -name '*.log*' -mtime 15 -exec rm -f {} +
```

A diferença é que a primeira opção executa o comando `rm -f` uma vez para cada arquivo encontrado, enquanto que a segunda opção passa vários nomes de arquivos de uma vez para o `rm -f`, reduzindo a quantidade de vezes que o comando roda.

---

Outra opção é fazer um *pipe* (`|`) e usar o comando `xargs`:

```
find  -name '*.log*' -mtime 15 |xargs rm -f
```

Com isso, a saída do `find` (os nomes dos arquivos) são passados como parâmetros para o comando `rm -f` (similar à opção com `+` acima).

---

[Veja a documentação](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) para mais detalhes.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou